# How to capture error and print stream of c program trigger from java

Tags: java, c, shell, gcc

`C` code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
printf("Expected to print");
int a = 1/0;
return 0;
}
```

compile it using

```
gcc Test.c
```

From `java` running

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

here `cmd` is `[/bin/bash, -c, ./a.out]`
and then i capture the errorStream of the process `p.getErrorStream()`
but errorStream does not have the `Floating point exception` in it which we get if we run

```
./a.out
```

from console

Comment: why dont you use JNI

Comment: The text `Expected to print` from the `printf` doesn't appear because it was not flushed to `stdout` prior to the exception. A `\n` at the end of the text should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

`Floating point exception` isn't printed from the program but by `bash`. If you interactively start the program and the program got the `FPE` `bash` prints the `FPE` message.

With `bash -c a.out` `bash` just calls one of the `exec()` functions without calling `fork()` before and thus is directly replaced by `a.out` hence it can't print out anything.

I get `Floating point exception (core dumped)` in the Java error stream if I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash","-i","-c","echo -n;./a.out"});`.

With the `echo -n`,which does nothing,  `bash` is forced to stay alive and so can print out the `FPE` message. The `-i` sets the `bash` to interactive mode.